# Regular expression for search condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to validate condition which user enter in text box. Say in my case condition would be **(1 and (2 or 3))or 4) and 5**
So here i want that string can contain properly closed braces,digit and AND OR keyword.
Can anyone please help me to create regular expression to validate this kind of string

Comment: will code for food

Comment: precise examples would be helpful

Comment: Javascript doesn't have full recursive Regexes, so it isn't possible in a single regex (you need recursive regexes for the brakets).

Comment: You don't want a regular expression. You don't want a regular expression. You don't want a regular expression. You want a tokenizer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. use | for alternation.
Alternation matches content on either side of the alternation character.

Example: /(a|b)a/ matches 'aa' in "dseaas" and 'ba' in "acbab".

Refer to: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml